# Using AutoFac constructor injection in a console application on different classes

Tags: c#, autofac, constructor-injection

So I have the idea that I'm missing something here, but I'm basically making a console application that will call multiple handlers.

> Program.cs

```
private static IContainer _container;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _container = AutoFacBootstrapper.Init();
    var _backupFactory = _container.Resolve<IBackupFactory>();

    UserHandler.Init();
}
```

> AutoFacBootstrapper.cs

```
public static IContainer Init()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<BackupFactory>().As<IBackupFactory>();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

See all of this is nice and fun and I can use my factories in Program.cs, but when I try to use my factory in a different class (lets say UserHandler.cs), my `_backupFactory` will remain null (which makes sense).

> UserHandler.cs

```
private static IBackupFactory _backupFactory;
public UserHandler(IBackupFactory backupFactory)
{
    _backupFactory = backupFactory;
}

public static void Init(string[] subCommands)
{
    var users = _backupFactory.GetFtpUsers();
}
```

How do I fix this, so I can use the constructor injection in another class, while only having to initialise it on startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `_backupFactory` is null because the `UserHandler` constructor is never called.

To solve this you would also need to create an interface for `UserHandler` and register the type in the `AutoFacBootstrapper`.

```
interface IUserHandler
{
    void PerformSomeAction();
}

class UserHandler : IUserHandler
{
    private IBackupFactory _backupFactory;
    public UserHandler(IBackupFactory backupFactory)
    {
        _backupFactory = backupFactory;
    }

    public void PerformSomeAction()
    {
        var users = _backupFactory.GetFtpUsers();
    }
}

class AutoFacBootstrapper
{
    public static IContainer Init()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<UserHandler>().As<IUserHandler>();
        builder.RegisterType<BackupFactory>().As<IBackupFactory>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

What is left, is for Autofac to resolve the `IUserHandler` type in the `Main` method.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IContainer container = AutoFacBootstrapper.Init();

        IUserHandler startPoint = container.Resolve<IUserHandler>();
        startPoint.PerformSomeAction();
    }
```

As a side note, as the application is growing bigger and bigger and new projects will be created, registering all the types of the application in the `AutoFacBootstrap` class is not indicated.

It will be better to have a separate class in each project that will inherit `Autofac.Module` which will have an override of the `Load` method. This way you will have access to the `ContainerBuilder` and be able to register all the desired types (from that assembly).

Check out the [Modules](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html) section from the Autofac documentation for more details

Comment: I'll take a look at the Modules later, but having my Handlers injected aswel was a great idea, thanks!